# Why is my ORDER BY in STRING_AGG not always working?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have a table that consists of a record ID, a group ID (linking 1 or more records into a group) and a hash value for each record.

```
CREATE TABLE HashTable(
    RecordID VARCHAR(255),
    GroupIdentifier VARCHAR(255),
    Hash VARCHAR (255),
    GroupHashList VARCHAR(4000)
)
```

(I know this isn't an efficient table, but it's just a temp table for the purposes of this example).

I want to generate a hash for each group, so I thought the simplest way would be to concatenate the hashes of each record in the group. RecordIDs are unique, but what those records relate to are not necessarily unique so the hashes may be duplicates. The point of this is to flag fully duplicate groups ie a group were all records in that group are duplicates of all records in another group. The GUI needs all members of the group to have the same hash if it's to recognise them as a duplicate group.

I'm using STRING_AGG to concatenate the individual hashes of the records in the group, and sorting them by the hash to make sure I get the same string of characters for duplicate groups. I don't actually care what the order of the hashes is, so long as it's the same each time. When I run it as a SELECT query, it works fine and I can see identical strings for duplicate groups. When I take that same SELECT query and put it into an UPDATE query, the ordering seems to get lost.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG([Hash],';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Hash] ASC) 
FROM HashTable
GROUP BY [GroupIdentifier]
```

This gives the results (for an example pair of duplicate groups):

```
73F294873462B2BA0E930FD16DCCB7;90E749375DF806CB6E3F5CA48FFA38;E44256CE7CFCB971EB679BAC25A697
73F294873462B2BA0E930FD16DCCB7;90E749375DF806CB6E3F5CA48FFA38;E44256CE7CFCB971EB679BAC25A697
```

When I put that same code into the UPDATE query, it doesn't sort them correctly:

```
UPDATE HashTable
SET GroupHashList = c.HashList
FROM HashTable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT (STRING_AGG([Hash],';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Hash] ASC)) AS [HashList],
        [GroupIdentifier]
    FROM HashTable
    GROUP BY [GroupIdentifier]) c
ON c.[GroupIdentifier] = HashTable.[GroupIdentifier]
```

Results for the same two groups that gets written to the table:

```
73F294873462B2BA0E930FD16DCCB7;90E749375DF806CB6E3F5CA48FFA38;E44256CE7CFCB971EB679BAC25A697
73F294873462B2BA0E930FD16DCCB7;E44256CE7CFCB971EB679BAC25A697;90E749375DF806CB6E3F5CA48FFA38
```

What am I missing?

What I'm getting the first time is

```
Hash1; Hash2; Hash3
Hash1; Hash2; Hash3
```

But when it's in the UPDATE query, I get

```
Hash1; Hash2; Hash3
Hash1; Hash3; Hash2
```

The update query is sorted by record ID, although I don't know if that's coincidence. (https://dbfiddle.uk/CPG1-z2l)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This appears to be a bug in the optimizer.**

The optimizer, having realized that the join is a self-join, is transforming it into a window aggregate. It can do this despite `STRING_AGG` not being available as a window aggregate. The rule is called [*GenGbApplySimple*](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/07/cool-query-plan-transformation-of-the-day.html), and allows a self-join to be converted to a window aggregate. There is nothing specifically wrong with this so far.

[image: Plan]

[PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkBSL3BXs)

**The problem is that the aggregation is over the wrong value.** It is aggregating the outer value rather than the inner one.

If you give the two references different aliases, then a careful examination of the query plan reveals the bug.

```
STRING_AGG([dbo].[HashTable].[Hash] as [HT1].[Hash],'')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [HT2].[Hash])
```

The other issue is that the aggregates used with that rule (e.g. `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`) don't have a `WITHIN GROUP` ordering to satisfy, so the replacement plan doesn't account for it. It seems likely that `STRING_AGG` was not intended to work the *GbApply* rules, or work would be needed to make it compatible (honouring the sort request).

As you can see below, the *Sort* only orders by the correlation column `GroupIdentifier`, not by the `Hash` column used in the `WITHIN GROUP`.

```xml
<OrderBy>
  <OrderByColumn Ascending="1">
    <ColumnReference
      Database="[...]"
      Schema="[dbo]"
      Table="[HashTable]"
      Alias="[HT1]"
      Column="GroupIdentifier">
    </ColumnReference>
  </OrderByColumn>
</OrderBy>
```

---

If you are a `sysadmin`, you can turn this rule off for the query, by using the following undocumented `OPTION`.

```sql
OPTION (QUERYRULEOFF GenGbApplySimple)
```

---

As a workaround, one option to prevent this optimization being applied is to use a grouped `OUTER APPLY`

```sql
UPDATE HT1
SET GroupHashList = C.HashList
OUTPUT inserted.*
FROM HashTable AS HT1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        HashList =
            STRING_AGG(HT2.[Hash], ';')
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY HT2.[Hash] ASC)
    FROM HashTable AS HT2
    WHERE HT2.GroupIdentifier = HT1.GroupIdentifier
) C;
```

This gets you a pretty straightforward self-join with a *Stream Aggregate*.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/6vlI4DCL)

---

**I strongly suggest you [file this as a bug](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-get-help) with Microsoft.**

You could also [leave feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0), but that does not typically lead to a specific response.

---

As an aside, you should follow the aliasing rules suggested by [Conor Cunningham](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/205249/conor-cunningham-msft) when writing multi-table `UPDATE` statements:

> The non-ANSI FROM clause (which you are using here) has specific binding behaviors that may or may not be what you expect.  I will suggest you start by aliasing the 3 references to hashtable to be different and then make sure you are explicitly refering to the one you want.  It may be (I am guessing) that it is binding to a different one than you think and providing you an undesired output as a result.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT The bug also appears in SQL Server 2022, when using the new `APPROX_PERCENTILE_CONT` and a `WITHIN GROUP` specification, along with a self-join. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJtup6zEo

Comment: I don't have a strict timeline for a fix, but it is on the list of things I've assigned one of my engineers to do as part of their current project.  If you have a production issue with this, please contact Customer Support and they can work on pushing for a more expedited fix as business needs require.